# Tuya python script doesn't connect. Error 501

Tags: python, sdk, iot, tuya

When I'm trying to connect to tuya api using tuya_iot library, I get a generic error that says nothing.

I tried this:

```py
from tuya_iot import TuyaOpenAPI, TUYA_LOGGER
import logging

TUYA_LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

# Cloud project authorization info
ACCESS_ID = 'mysuperID'
ACCESS_KEY = 'mysuperSecretKey'

# For more info, refer to: https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/api-request?id=Ka4a8uuo1j4t4
ENDPOINT = "https://openapi.tuyaus.com" # Western America Data Center

# Project configuration
USERNAME = 'myemail@mail.com'
PASSWORD = 'thePassword of Tuya'

# Initialization of tuya openapi
openapi = TuyaOpenAPI(ENDPOINT, ACCESS_ID, ACCESS_KEY)
openapi.connect(USERNAME, PASSWORD)
```

And I got this:

```
[2023-11-13 18:44:47,778] [tuya-openapi] Request: method = POST,                 url = https://openapi.tuyaus.com/v1.0/iot-01/associated-users/actions/authorized-login,                params = None,                body = {'username': 'myemail@mail.com', 'password': '***', 'country_code': '', 'schema': ''},                t = 1699911887778
[2023-11-13 18:44:48,694] [tuya-openapi] Response: {
  "code": 501,
  "msg": "request fail with unkown error",
  "success": false,
  "t": 1699911889502,
  "tid": "debb0af0826d11ee8088063dea7c5c23"
}
```

But I was hoping to get a successful connection.

Comment: Is that output from the `TuyaOpenAPI(...)` call, or the `openapi.connect(...)` call?

Comment: The output is from the `openapi.connect(...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research I find out this library which is simpler to use and easier overall. [TinyTuya](https://github.com/jasonacox/tinytuya)

```py
import tinytuya

# Tuya connection
tuya_api_endpoint = os.getenv('TUYA_API_ENDPOINT')
tuya_access_id = os.getenv('TUYA_ACCESS_ID')
tuya_access_key = os.getenv('TUYA_ACCESS_KEY')

# Connecto to Tuya API
tuya_cloud = tinytuya.Cloud(apiRegion = tuya_api_endpoint, apiKey = tuya_access_id, apiSecret = tuya_access_key)
# API_ENDPOINT: cn, us, us-e, eu, eu-w, or in. Options based on tinytuya python library
```

And using this one is easier to connect to the Tuya API, as the functions are really straight forward and have great documentation.

Answer (score 0):

I could fix this issue after installing the following library:

```
pip3 install tuya-connector-python
```

I found this one on the first step, part 3 of the following documentation:
https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/device-control-best-practice-python?id=Kav4zc0nphsn5

After that I only did:

```
from tuya_connector import TuyaOpenAPI

# Cloud project authorization info
ACCESS_ID = 'mysuperID'
ACCESS_KEY = 'mysuperSecretKey'

# For more info, refer to: https://developer.tuya.com/en/docs/iot/api-request?id=Ka4a8uuo1j4t4
API_ENDPOINT= 'https://openapi.tuyaus.com' # Western America Data Center
    
# Init OpenAPI and connect
openapi = TuyaOpenAPI(API_ENDPOINT, ACCESS_ID, ACCESS_KEY)
openapi.connect()
```

and it worked just fine.